# Runtime Error :SQLiteException: near "contact": syntax error app stopped working

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, fatal-error

I have created a sign up activity with an SQlite database and I got a runtime error in my app when I hit the sign button.Stacktrace leads me to line  36 in the class DatabaseHelper I have created for the database and then shows an error in signup activity but I just cannot resolve them. Any help and ideas would be really useful

PS(Im new in android development and in stackoverflow so sorry for the long post and perhaps obvious errors
Here is the stacktrace

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "contact": syntax error
06-29 17:48:21.680 5897-5897/kanepraktiki2017.xyz.mreprogramming.kanepraktiki E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                Process: kanepraktiki2017.xyz.mreprogramming.kanepraktiki, PID: 5897
                                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4240)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20893)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4235)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184) 
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20893) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                                                                 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "contact": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create contact table(id integer primary key not null , name text not null, email text not null , username text not null, password text not null);
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1798)
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1729)
                                                                                                    at kanepraktiki2017.xyz.mreprogramming.kanepraktiki.DabaseHelper.onCreate(DabaseHelper.java:36)
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                                    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                                    at kanepraktiki2017.xyz.mreprogramming.kanepraktiki.DabaseHelper.insertContact(DabaseHelper.java:41)
                                                                                                    at kanepraktiki2017.xyz.mreprogramming.kanepraktiki.Signup.onSignUpClick(Signup.java:49)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4235) 
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184) 
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20893) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
```

And the DatabaseHelper.java code$

```
Public class DabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_name = "contacts.db";
private static final String TABLE_name = "contacts";
private static final String COLUMN_id = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_name = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_email = "email";
private static final String COLUMN_username = "username";
private static final String COLUMN_password = "password";
SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String TABLE_create = "create contact table(id integer primary key not null , " +
        "name text not null, email text not null , username text not null, password text not null);";

public DabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(TABLE_create);
    this.db = db;
}

public void insertContact(Contact c) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String query="select * from contacts";
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count=cursor.getCount();

    values.put(COLUMN_id, count);
    values.put(COLUMN_name, c.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_email, c.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_username, c.getUsername());
    values.put(COLUMN_password, c.getPassword());

    db.insert(DATABASE_name, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public String searchpass(String username) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select username, password from" + TABLE_name;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String a, b;
    b = "Δεν βρέθηκε";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            a = cursor.getString(0);
            if (a.equals(username)) {
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
     return b;
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    String query ="Drop Table If Exists"+TABLE_name;
    db.execSQL(query);
    this.onCreate(db);

}
}
```

Comment: please format your question

Comment: `CREATE Contact TABLE ...` is not a valid SQL command.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but still error occurs

Comment: Don't invalidate all the answers by editing your question to remove the original issue. If you have another question, ask a new question (after making the appropriate effort to solve it yourself). Read [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry ,I didn't have such an intention thats why I answer all the reseived answer and I am thankful for that I just thought Its no need to create another question since the problem still remains the same

Comment: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts (code 1): , while compiling: select * from contacts`. Now the new error says that you are trying to find your rows in a table named `contacts`. But you created a table named `contact`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement to create the new table in not valid. You habe to switch the keyword `table` and the tablename. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE contact 
(
   id integer primary key not null,
   name text not null, 
   email text not null, 
   username text not null, 
   password text not null
);
```

Also there is failure in this statement.

```
 String query="select * from contacts";
```

You can use your variable TABLE_name for that but have to change the name of the table there.

```
private static final String TABLE_name = "contact";
```

Then change your SQL statement like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM" + this.TABLE_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I changed it but still the problems occurs

Comment: Do you get the same error? What does your sql statement looks like now?

Comment: yes with the difference that now I get errors in lines (DabaseHelper.java:45) and in my signup class. Sql I' ve changed as you indicated 'create table contact(...  (I 've changed it also in my code above)

Comment: For what I see you still have a bad statement. You should change "select * from contacts" to "select * from contact". That could be the reason for the error.

Comment: The value of the variable TABLE_name is contacts although your table was named "contact". You should change that!

Answer (score 0):

Change your statement to this one:

```
"create table contact(id integer primary key not null , " +
        "name text not null, email text not null , username text not null, password text not null);"
```

instead of "create contact table(...)" it should be "create table contact(...)"

Edit: If you are still getting an error change this line:

```
 String query="select * from contacts";
```

to this:

```
 String query="select * from contact";
```

Also, if you keep getting errors, it may be because you are trying to recreate a table that has already been created. Please go learn SQL, SQLite, and Andriod database connections so you can know how it actually works. Internet research can go a long way in helping you understand highly documented topics like these

Comment: Thanks for the observation ,but unfortunately problem is still on

Comment: @Stefania what is the new error?

Comment: Simply saying that you have a problem is completely useless - we need to know what the exact problem is with exact error messages and exact description.

Comment: I' ll make an update above but its doesnt have much difference..the line 36 dousnt appear

Comment: @Stefania I looked at your updated exception and it looks like you didn't even change your sql statement to what my answer says

Comment: @Stefania I found another error in your code. I edited my answer

Comment: @JamalH you re right sorry I thought i have edited it but maybe I didnt save it I dont know..in my original code I have made the correction

Comment: Actually I ve followed a tutorial on this, I havent written it myself so it had to be working..But maybe you re right table has been already created cause new error  is : there is not such table a contacts.db... Anyway thanks I 'll check it out

Comment: @Stefania that error is because you named your table "contact" when you were creating it, so that is why "contacts.db" does not exist. It is named contact, not contacts. Either change your call statement to get the table contact, or try this: 

when you are creating your table, put this "create table contacts(..."